# Print preview using custom paginator and XpsDocumentWriter not displaying in DocumentViewer

Tags: c#, mvvm, pagination, documentviewer

I have created a custom document paginator that takes a datatable and prints exactly as I need.  I would like to do a print preview.  I have read all the posts on how to create a xps file in memory and then display it.  I just can't get it to work. Here is my code. I am using a MVVM pattern. Please note the line of code _data.DocView=fds; This passes the data to my view model.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            dialog.ShowDialog();
            StoreDataSetPaginator paginator = new StoreDataSetPaginator(dt, new Typeface("Calibri"), 8, 96 * 0.75,
                new Size(dialog.PrintableAreaWidth, dialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
                    //this is commented out to attempt the print preview
                    // dialog.PrintDocument(paginator, "Print out");


            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            Package package = Package.Open(ms, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            Uri DocumentUri = new Uri("pack://InMemoryDocument.xps");
            PackageStore.AddPackage(DocumentUri, package);
            XpsDocument xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.NotCompressed,
                DocumentUri.AbsoluteUri);
            XpsDocumentWriter writer = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsDocument);

            writer.Write(paginator);
            IDocumentPaginatorSource fds = xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
            _data.DocView = fds;

            PrintPreviewConduit prntv = new PrintPreviewConduit();
            prntv.Show();
```

Now here is my view model:

```
private IDocumentPaginatorSource _docView;
    public IDocumentPaginatorSource DocView
    {
        get { return _docView; }
        set
        {
            _docView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DocView");
        }
    }
```

And finally my XAML:

```
<Grid>
   <DocumentViewer Name="docview" Document="{Binding DocView}"/>
</Grid>
```

I entered a break point in my ViewModel at "public IDocumentPaginatorSource DocView" and when I roll my mouse over it I get "System.Windows.Documents.FixedDocumentSequence.  Not sure what i should be getting. I spent a good while now and any help would be greatly appreciated.
Sys

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel stupid. I did not set the new window's datacontext to my view model. Now everything works!!!!

```
PrintPreviewConduit prntv = new PrintPreviewConduit();
prntv.DataContext = _data;
_data.DocView = fds;
prntv.Show();
```